# Jquery ajax POST call in MVC - include application name hosted in IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

I am try to use Jquery ajax call - to call one of the controller method, I am using like below.
However when in localhost the URL formation is fine.
I  tried to deploy my application in IIS and created as a separate application, so my URL will be like
http://website.com/applicationame/Contollername/methodname.

But while using url: "/Contollername/methodname" --- in my ajx call in js file it is finding the contoller method in :

http://website.com/Contollername/methodname. -- **leaving out the application name** and throwing error.

Application Name can vary across environments so cannot hardcode. Please let me know if there is a way to handle this.

This ajax call is in separate js file.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Contoller/MethodName",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple options. The situation you are describing is using virtual paths. MVC Razor views can handle virtual paths with the tilda key (~/myrelativeurl). What I would suggest is letting MVC generate the URL and then use that in your Javascript.

A way would be to use a global Javascript variable to contain the URL that MVC has generated for you, then you can use that URL in your jQuery call.

```
<script>
// whole URL
var callUrl = '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")';
// just the root (this will be the virtual path, if any)
var siteRoot = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
</script>
```

EDIT: as a backup measure you could also fetch the domain + virtual path from the current browser window, but this is obviously not as reliable and maintainable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Just to be sure -- in my view i will assign :
var callUrl = '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")'; ------- which I can use in the stand alone js. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, as long as your script is loaded in after your content or starts on document ready. So you could place that code in your Layout.cshtml, at the very top.